# Netbeans -> not recognising methods from classes in the Libraries

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 8.1 I'm trying find if an array is empty using the `isEmpty()` method in the `ArrayList` class. 
However, when I try to call it it gives me the "cannot find symbol" hint.
I have imported `java.util.ArrayList` and that gives me the "Unused Import" hint.

I've tried it with `size()` and `add()` as well, which are both methods from `ArrayList`, to the same success.

It's not misspelled, and `java.util.ArrayList` is definitely in the libraries.

I've also tried

- deleting the cache,
- clean and build and
- copying everything to a new project

if that makes any difference.

Comment: **How** are you calling this?

Comment: Can you show us source code?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
import java.util.*;
```

This will import all from that package, if this does not work make sure you have all the JDK they can be downloaded here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.